# adding scroll item on top tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to do something like newsfeed but much simpler. Just items getting populated from the top, and old items are pushed down. I am taking reference from [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter) but this one adds new item on the bottom, and I could not make it so that the newest one is always added on top and old ones are on the bottom. Thank you in advance.
I have this so far:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")

row=0

def populate(frame):
    global row
    row += 1

            #image files
    imfile = "potato.jpeg"
    im=Image.open(imfile)
    resized=im.resize((50,50), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

    t="the item number %s \t\t" %row 


    tk.Label(frame, text=t, compound=tk.RIGHT).pack()

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def update_status():
    populate(frame)
    root.after(1000, update_status)


root.after(1000, update_status)
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
root.geometry("500x500")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "fb" stand for? Also, please create a [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried. Pay close attention to the "M" and "C"

Comment: facebook, or can be news feed. just basically meant stack. which newest item added on top

Comment: `.pack(side="top")` on your items would be the obvious solution - does that not work?

Comment: @jasonharper `pack` doesn't quite work like that, though that can be part of the solution. You have to remember that "top" means the top of the available space, and if other things are also packed to the top, the available space will be below them.

Comment: then is there maybe a way to push the packed things down? or should i have used a different library or tool?

Comment: Yes there is. I recommend reading the `pack` documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found it out:

```
tk.Label(frame, text=t,image=tkimage, compound=tk.RIGHT).pack(side="bottom")
b=Button(frame, text="see more for %s" %row, command=new_window).pack(side="bottom")
```